# jQuery Set active tab from URL

Tags: jquery, tabs

i have this tab-system:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabs div').hide();
    $('#tabs div:first').show();
    $('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
    $('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){
        if($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
            /** active **/
        } else {
            $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#tabs div').hide();
            $(currentTab).show('slide', {}, 500);
        }
        return false;
    });
});

<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tab-1">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-2">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-3">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-4">4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab-5">5</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="tab-1">
Content tab1
</div>
<div tab2... etc
```

If i add #tab-3 at the end of the URL, it should automaticly show and set tab 3 active without me have to click it.

Is this possible in a simple way?

Comment: if you are applying the code $('#tabs div:first').show(); and $('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active'); every time the document is ready, aren't you going to display the 1st tab no matter what your url is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edited after looking at your code further -

if you code in these two lines every time the DOM is ready you are always going to see that first tab.

```
$('#tabs div:first').show();
$('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
```

your going to have to check the url for a '#tab' first before you decide if you should show the first tab.

```
$(function(){
    ...
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if(hash){
        $('a[href="' + hash +'"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
        var elementID = hash.replace('#', '');
        $(elementID).show();
    } else {
        $('#tabs div:first').show();
        $('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works great. This is the final code: http://pastebin.com/G3x7D1ET

Answer (score 2):

This should probably work:

```
$(window).bind( 'hashchange', function( event ) {
    var hash=window.location.hash;
    if(!hash){return;}
    $('a[href="'+hash+'"]').click();
});​
$(window).trigger('hashchange');
```

Comment: Well, it works. But the point of this was that i can link a tab from another site/file. If i open a new tab, paste mysite.com/t#tab-3 it shows the first tab. If i hit enter again (when the site is loaded) it loads tab-3. Is there a way that it loads the tab directly?

Comment: What do you mean by `If i open a new tab, paste mysite.com/t#tab-3 it shows the first tab.`?